# Root component as React.component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-boilerplate

I'm using [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate) and I'm trying to change the [App component](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/containers/App/index.js) to extend `React.Component`, since I'm trying to implement authentication and displaying/showing side menu depending on authentication state by following [this example](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-with-shared-root/components/App.js). As you can see, originally props are passed to App via props parameter. I've changed the `App/index.js` class to this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from 'components/Header';
import SideMenu from 'containers/SideMenu';
import Footer from 'components/Footer';
import auth from 'utils/auth'

export class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
  console.log(props)
  return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <SideMenu />
        {React.Children.toArray(props.children)}
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  children: React.PropTypes.node,
};

export default App;
```

This throws an error that props are not defined:

> ReferenceError: props is not defined
>   App.render
>   **/App/index.js

You can see how root route is instantiated [here](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/app.js):

```
// Set up the router, wrapping all Routes in the App component
import App from 'containers/App';
import createRoutes from './routes';
const rootRoute = {
  component: App,
  childRoutes: createRoutes(store),
};
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
this.props.children
```

Also you dont need to change the children to array

**simply use:**

```
 {this.props.children}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works. Confused a little though, so if I call this.props it's a parameter of the class, and if I only use props, it's an object in the global scope? Doesn't it look up the class variables also?

Comment: If you want to use a class variable its always through 'this'. using without 'this' will always look for either a global variable or something you defined inside of the method, but not on the class itself. In React props and state are on the class itself, and you always need to access it via this.state/ this.props

Comment: Thank you :) That explains things